# Windows xp registry permission problems

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, windows-registry, administrator, limited-user-account

this one has me banging my head against a brick wall.
Basically the computer in question has had it's problems but we have done a windows xp repair and got all the windows updates in and done got a fresh load of software on the machine so we thought we were all good.

Then we made a limited account and bascially there are 2 problems both linked with the registry. The first being windows messenger and when you try and log in the typing is slow and in the end gives you an error and basically it's no dice. 
I've googled the error and it gives you a set of instructions for some dll files to run and that fails on the second one. Now I've kinda got around that by installing a open source messenger and job done.

Problems number 2.
So I've installed open office and basically in this limited account the files that should be associated with open office aren't. So no biggy just go to folders etc and make the file association but that didn't work, so I tried the command line assoc and that doesn't work.

If I make this user a administrator all the problems go away, now I've been to the regedit area there seems to be a permission. But I'm not very hot on this stuff and don't want to make a mess on it.

I've tried a few registry cleanups and no dice, it's all just annoying.
If anyone has any ideas or anything please post!
Thanks
Richard

Comment: Have you tried to make the user a power user?

Comment: Have you run the applications at least once as the Administrator or a member of the Administrators group?

Comment: Your question about the registry is broad and without specific information as yo what registry keys you are talking about, no way any of us can answer this question in its present form. Registry questions need to be very specific.

Comment: I assume we're talking about a local user not on a domain? How about if you create a new user? Do they have same issues? Have you tried this? **http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/reset-the-registry-and-the-file-permissions-in-windows-xp/**

Comment: Hi how do I make the user a power user?
Just so you know it's just on a single machine not using microsoft network which I think is what all the group stuff is about.

Comment: Trying the subacl stuff now fingers crossed - I'll get back to u

Comment: Hi the subacl stuff fired but didn't work the problems with registry are with windows live messenger - the error code is 8004883 and open office odt extension that won't work

Comment: Yeah just made a new user and th account had the same problems.
Hope this helps - any other ideas!

Comment: File associations are computer wide not just for a user profile. So to change those you will have to do it as an admin.

Comment: Yeah they work of for the admin but not for the limited user.
It's a real puzzler!